# 'Election ended' is off

Tags: bug, status-completed, election-page

It seems the 'election ended' information on election statistics pages is... off. For example, take [this election](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#electronics.stackexchange) which ended Mar 3, 2014, almost a year ago:

[image]

I'm not sure *how* the current number is calculated exactly, but this doesn't seem to be correct. It works on any election page, by the way.

Comment: That's odd it does have the correct date when you hover over it.

Comment: [Yeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah...](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) But the caching is incorrect. I knew about this and forgot to fix it, will get it patched up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since election information isn't available via the API, the election statistics site scrapes the elections page for the relevant information, including the time periods for the various stages that are listed in the sidebar of [the election page on the site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/3).

We do this every so often as people request the information for that site's election, but to avoid needlessly scraping the page we cache the scraped response data *permanently* on the first scrape that happens after the election completes, since nothing on the page changes after that point.

…except of course the shortened date texts, since, y'know, those are time-relative. Whoops! We probably could just do with not storing that particular label to begin with, but as a quick fix I just recompute the relative mini timestamp if the election finished, since I happened to have a method to do that handy already.

I deployed the update, so it should be correct now. I also fixed a double-encoding issue in site names too for good measure.